# Using Custom Authentication on Wowza Client Requests

Tags: authentication, video-streaming, rtmp, wowza

Is it possible to use custom authentication, wherein each request for a stream is authenticated from my database and then a user is allowed to view a stream?

I've configured `Wowza IDE` for custom authentication using the following:

[Integrating Wowza User Authentication with External Authentication](https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-integrate-wowza-user-authentication-with-external-authentication-systems-modulertmpauthenticate)

but I do not know exactly where this works? As in how do I make a request for a stream with `authentication credentials` that are eventually checked by this module's logic?

I am new to `Wowza` and `Video Streaming` as well.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

take a look into documentation, perhaps there is something more convenient, like flussonic authentication mechanism that will just send HTTP request once per some time.

Comment: Flussonic's Process seems simple, but I am not sure how something similar might work in Wowza. I guess my best bet is to develop process similar to Flussonic's process for authentication purpose?

Comment: I didn't find much similar to Flussonic's Process except the pluggable authentication mechanisms that work directly on the RTMP stream data.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a diagram](https://streamtoolbox.com/authentication-mechanism) that shows you how this works in a similar module, you can try to mimic this idea in your own plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in wowza custom module. There are two methods onConnect and onConnectAccept. Implement your logic in onConnectAccept and make authentication against DB or whatever you need.